# Retrieve element 'value', by searching 'name'

Tags: c#, xml

I'm positive this is a simple question, but I can't figure it out.

I'm downloading an XML file to a string in C#, and it contains items in the following format:

```
<attribute name="Make" value="Volvo" />
<attribute name="Color" value="Blue" />
<attribute name="Damage" value="Rear scratched" />
<attribute name="Damage" value="Left hand side dented" />
```

And all I want to do is get *all* of the values for "Damage" in the whole document (Regardless of where they fall) into an array. I've been playing with XmlDocument / XmlNodeList but I just can't figure out how to get this working.

I'm half tempted to do it with RegEx but that feels very very dirty.

Comment: Use Linq to XML = fast and easy to read code. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "XML / C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `XDocument`:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var result = doc.Descendants("attribute")
                .Where(x => x.Attribute("name") != null &&
                            x.Attribute("value") != null)
                .Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "Damage")
                .Select(x => x.Attribute("value").Value)
                .ToArray();
```

Please note:
This code is relatively simple, because it takes all `attribute` nodes in the whole document into account.

Comment: caveat: The list of attributes in the question will not work with this code "as-is".  There is no "root element".  if the "attribute" elements had a parent "attributes" element then this code sample works perfectly.

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive: That's not a problem with this code but with the provided sample data, because that is simply no valid XML and I assumed the OP only showed the relevant part.

Comment: Just of interest, why you've used two `Where()` expressions

Comment: @sll: I found it slightly easier to read this way. The first `Where` clause filters out all attributes that don't have the required attributes. This is necessary to avoid a `NullReferenceException` and can be seen as a purely technical filter. The second `Where` clause is the "business filter".

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks. @DanielHilgarth - as said, the full document is valid XML.

Answer (score 1):

```
string val = "";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();  

doc.Load("file.xml");

XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/attribute[@name='Damage']");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
   {
      val = node.Attributes["value"].Value; 
   }
}
```

should work?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth code was edited since my original comment, which I will remove now in response to the edit fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage LINQ-TO-XML but you've to provide it a rigth XML, so just create a root node manually otherwise you will end up with `System.Xml.XmlException : There are multiple root elements.`.

```
// raw - your XML
string raw = File.ReadAllText("c:\\test1.xml");

// create root node manually
string xml = "<root>" + raw + "</root>";
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);       

// contains IEnumerable<string>
// TODO: add null-checks
var damagedValues = xdoc.Descendants("attribute")
                        .Where(e => e.Attribute("name").Value == "Damage")
                        .Select(e => e.Attribute("value").Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's not an XML Document, it is a fragment. You need to wrap it with a root element. This'll work:

```
string fragment = File.ReadAllText("file.xml");
var doc = XDocument.Parse("<root>" + fragment  + "</root>");

var values = from element in doc.XPathSelectElements(@"//attribute[@name='Damage']")
             select element.Attribute("value").Value;

values.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```